# On page load Add Class to div if the class of the selected option in a dropdown equals a value

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a search form that uses dropdowns to search within a specific category.  I need to add a class to a div on the search results page if the selected option contains a specific class.

Here are my select options in the search form:

```
<select  name='product_cat' id='product_cat' class='cat-dropdown hidden-xs' >
<option value='0'>Search All</option>
<option class="level-0" value="antibodies">Antibodies</option>
<option class="level-0" value="chemicals" selected="selected">Chemicals</option>
<option class="level-0" value="elisa-kits">Elisa Kits</option>
<option class="level-0" value="chromatography">Chromatography</option>
```

I have another div further down the page I would like to add a class to if the class of the selected option equals "level-0".  I would like this to happen NOt during the select process but on the search results page when it loads.

Here is what I have so far but I cannot get it working:

```html
$('#product_cat option').load(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'level-0'){ 

$("#sidebar-fwp-type").addClass("hideme");  // Add class to our facet

  }
});
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if the selected option has a specific class, but you check for the value instead: `if($(this).val() == 'level-0')`. Note that the load() event is [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) as of jQuery 3.0 and should be written as .`on( "load", handler )` instead of `.load( handler )`. Furthermore, it doesn't work like you intended:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

So you could use  `$(window).on('load', function (){})` if you want to wait until all images or other external resources are loaded. I'll just use `$(document).ready();` instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#product_cat option:selected").attr("class") == "level-0") {
    $("#sidebar-fwp-type").addClass("hideme");
  }
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  name='product_cat' id='product_cat' class='cat-dropdown hidden-xs' >
<option value='0'>Search All</option>
<option class="level-0" value="antibodies">Antibodies</option>
<option class="level-0" value="chemicals" selected="selected">Chemicals</option>
<option class="level-0" value="elisa-kits">Elisa Kits</option>
<option class="level-0" value="chromatography">Chromatography</option>
</select>
<div id="sidebar-fwp-type">
sidebar
</div>
```

Comment: @moorewebx Glad that I was able to help :) If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer so your question is resolved as answered/solved.